# How can I add reminder alert time in Google calendar URL

Tags: google-calendar-api

I am trying to create a link in my web page for adding an event in google calendar. The event start and end time are dynamic. The event is getting added in google calendar but the reminder time is taken as default i.e, 30 minutes. I want to make the reminder time as 1 day. The URL for adding the event is 
http://www.google.com/calendar/event?action=TEMPLATE&dates=20170717T063000Z%2F20170717T073000Z&text=My%20appointment

Could you please advise me if I can pass the reminder/ alert time also in this URL?

Comment: Can anyone please help me on this? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no way to specify the reminder time vie TEMPLATE action I believe.

Comment: They do have a publish event option but i have observed that when i share the link with someone the original event doesnt get displayed as it is.